# Node.js, coffeescript and compiled js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, nodemon

I understood it was possible to natively use CoffeeScript instead of JavaScript, without compiling the CoffeeScript files to JavaScript (at least not compiled them as files; Maybe in-memory or on-the-fly compilation).

I have a basic app with a main `app.coffee` file as following:

```
coffee = require 'coffee-script'
coffee = require 'coffee-script/register'
express = require 'express'
compression = require 'compression'
sockets = require 'socket.io'
http = require 'http'
server = http.createServer express
app = express()
# [...]
```

In my package.json I have the following:

```
// ...
"dependencies": {
  "coffee-script": "^1.9.3"
  // ...
}
"scripts": {
  "start": "coffee app.coffee --nodejs"
  // ...
}
// ...
```

I can run the app using `$> nodemon app.coffee`
or `$> coffee app.coffee`
or `$> npm start`

At some point when I re-run the application or save a CoffeeScript file, CoffeeScript file is compiled to a JavaScript file, and therefor every file in the folder tree end up getting duplicated in both a `.js` and a `.coffee` version, which I find pretty disturbing.

Also once there is a `.js` file for a module, I sometime feel like the application will use it in priority, and that changes in the CoffeeScript file are no longer taken in account.

- How can I avoid this behavior, and avoid file to be compiled every time ? Is it possible for the node engine to natively use the CoffeeScript files without creating a `.js` copy in the file tree?
- Of course I understand that the Node.js engine is a JavaScript engine, but is there a way to maybe compile/run files directly in-memory or in a different folder (since it might still be interesting to see the JavaScript output)?
- What is the exact interaction between the Node.js engine, the CoffeeScript compiler, and how can I understand this behavior ?

Answer (score 3):

I often use a small `.js` file to launch my code making the command to start my applications `node index.js` which contains this:

```
CoffeeScript = require('coffee-script');
CoffeeScript.register();
require('./src/main');
```

Change `./src/main` to the path to your coffee file.

It uses your coffee files to run your code giving stack traces etc.. that correspond to your coffee source.

Your `app.coffee` would not need to require coffee-script as you are already using coffee at that point.